# Spawn process then exit in haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm attempting to make a pop-up menu program for xmonad, and I'm trying to figure out how to spawn a command from a string, then exit without stopping or waiting for the child process.
I've gotten as far as using (using xmonad code as a template):

```
spawnPID x = forkProcess $ executeFile "/bin/sh" False ["-c", encodeString x] Nothing
```

At this point, I'm just not sure what to to do disassociate this child process from it's parent. Or if I'll need to use another method to start this process off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, this appears to work as I needed it to. I was able to run the external program, and it continued after the main program exited.
applicable source:

```
spawnPID :: String -> IO ProcessID
spawnPID x = forkProcess $ executeFile "/bin/sh" False ["-c", encodeString x] Nothing

spawn :: String -> IO ()
spawn x = spawnPID x >> return ()
```